# Change WordPress permalinks after a domain forwarding

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks, domain-forwarding

So here is the situation:

- I have a domain, **a.com** registered on **host1.com**
- I have a domain, **b.com** registered on **host2.com** and a Wordpress website on this     domain, hosted in the same hosting(host2.com).
- I forwarded **a.com** domain to **b.com** using the domain forwarding service of **host1.com**.

Now when I type a.com in my URL bar in my browser, I see the wordpress website from host2.com but because I masked a.com I still see a.com in my URL bar.
So far so good and this is exactly what I wanted to do.

Here begins the problem:
All internal links in my wordpress website are still linked to b.com.
For example if I click a post, the link is `b.com/posts?id=4` and the URL bar shows just a.com even when I go to that specific post and no matter to what page or post I click, the URL bar shows a.com.

What I want to achieve is to show `a.com/posts?id=2` or any other url pattern but with the a.com as prefix.

I know it's a little bad explained but I really need your help and would be happy to clarify any questions you had to fix this problem.
Thanks

Comment: So - should it *only ever* show a.com? Or if someone visits b.com, should the site show b.com at that time?  If it should only show a.com, then this is a simple htaccess redirect, you can find everywhere / been asked before.  If you want it to answer to both domains, then you're going to risk duplicate content penalties from Google, and you probably don't want that.

Comment: @cale_b Yes I just want it to show a.com and it's working now the way I want, but the problem is that it shows always a.com in the url bar no matter if I'm in the home page or in the posts page or in a specific post page or in the tags page etc. it always shows a.com. Could you please give me a reference to a question here or an article showing the htaccess script which is doing this? I would really appreciate this.